# Ray picking - get direction from pitch and yaw

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, raytracing, picking

I am attempting to cast a ray from the center of the screen and check for collisions with objects.

When rendering, I use these calls to set up the camera:

```
GL11.glRotated(mPitch, 1, 0, 0);
GL11.glRotated(mYaw, 0, 1, 0);
GL11.glTranslated(mPositionX, mPositionY, mPositionZ);
```

I am having trouble creating the ray, however. This is the code I have so far:

```
ray.origin = new Vector(mPositionX, mPositionY, mPositionZ);
ray.direction = new Vector(?, ?, ?);
```

My question is: what should I put in the question mark spots? I.e. how can I create the ray direction from the pitch and roll?

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question not unlike your's just recently. So I suggest you read this: [3d coordinate from point and angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162259/3d-coordinate-from-point-and-angles/8164840#8164840)

This applies to your question as well, only that you don't want just a point, but a ray. Well, remember that a point can be assumed a displacement-from-origin vector and that a ray is defined as

```
 r(t) = v*t + s
```

In your case, `s` is the camera position, and `v` would be a point relative to the camera's position. You figure the rest (or ask, if things are still unclear).